# How resize QLineEdit

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator, qlineedit

Having layout like below. In QT Design, right clicked on below layout and clicked on 'Break Layout' and resized the QlineEdit control. But when I select layout and clicked 'Layout in a Grid' the QlineEdit reset to original size. Resized QlineEdit control does not restored.

Original image:
[image: Original image]

Answer (score 0):

`QGridLayout` stretches all stretchable widgets in each column to have same width, you can limit widget's width using `maximumSize`